# how to get next Identity not the last inserted identity of Identity column

Tags: sql-server-2008

i have 2 table purchase and purchaseProduct 
purchase has primary key auto increment identity column 
is it possilbe to get next identity of identity column and lock it so nothing can get wrong to insert in purchaseProduct table

Comment: Do your inserts inside of a transaction.  That will guarantee that either all the inserts occur or none of them do.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do anything to "lock" an `IDENTITY` value. As soon as the table uses a value of an `IDENTITY`, it's used forever, even if you do a rollback. SQL Fiddle example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5fdb9/1/0. Note the `id`s that make it into the table, only 1 and 5.

If that doesn't address your problem, please revise your question.